# Release Compile Problems Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

Whenever I compile my program in debug mode it works perfectly fine, however when I compile it in Release mode I get the following errors:

```
moc_mainwindow.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `MainWindow::lowercase(QString)'
moc_mainwindow.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `MainWindow::on_label_linkActivated(QString const&)'
moc_mainwindow.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `MainWindow::on_ReadButton_clicked()'
:-1: error: release/moc_mainwindow.o: bad reloc address 0x4 in section `.data'
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The undefined error's are all pointing to functions I deleted in my program. I also "Ctrl-F"ed all of them in the moc_mainwindow.cpp and I couldn't find any of the functions. In addition usually when I double click the errors I usually get a reference showing where the error is in the code but it just says "File not found: moc_mainwindow.cpp"

Comment: Are you performing a clean build?

Comment: A clean build? Sorry im pretty new to QT

Comment: If you are using Qt on Windows and QtCreator, delete the `build-*` directories and simply press `CTRL+B` again. This will force QtCreator to generate again all the makefiles and compile all the objects, since they no longer exists.

Comment: Please, add ".h file" and ".cpp file" in your "QUESTION". Note `moc_mainwindow.cpp` is automatically generated.

Comment: Vinicius when I build all I get the errors as well. Also Guiherme what do you need me to add to the question?

Comment: I had the same errors. The error in my case was that there were obsolete functions declarations in my .h file. Remove or comment or obsolete function is your .h files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Qt Creator?  If so, to perform a clean you can choose "Rebuild All" from the build menu.  You can also choose "Clean", then right click your project and choose "Run qmake" to force regeneration of the make files:

[image]

Deleting the build directories will also work, as long as you are using the "Shadow Build" feature to ensure that your source and build are separate (it should be by default)

[image]

If you do have a shadow build, simply copy the build directory from the Projects > Build & Run > General pane, and delete it using your command line in the terminal.